# Is it possible to update MS Access database using Excel userform by using multiple conditions for WHERE SQL statement?

Tags: sql, vba, database, sql-update, where-clause

I am attempting to create an attendance monitoring system. One of its objective is to be able to update the attendance of a student upon taking attendance. In case the lecturer wants to change the attendance status.

Therefore, I have created a userform just to update attendance and it contains values for courseCode, subject, classDate, studentID, name, attendance status, and excuse. Is there a way to access my database (on access) through this userform to update the newest attendance status and excuse? I have tried using the method below but there is an error saying expected end of statement.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim db_path As String
Dim db_str As String

db_path = "filepath;"
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

db_str = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & db_path
cnt.Open (db_str)

insert_str = "update Classdate set attendanceStatus = '" & cmbUpdateStatus.Value & "' and Excuse = '" & txtUpdateExcuse.Value & "' where classDate = '" & cmbUpdateDate.Value "' and courseCode = '" & cmbUpdateCourseCode.Value & "' and studentID = '" & cmbUpdateStudentID.Value & "'"

cnt.Execute (insert_str)

MsgBox "Updated sucessfully", vbInformation

Set cnt = Nothing
```

Comment: There is missing an ampersand at: 
`cmbdateDate.Value "' and courseCode`

Comment: @RedHare thank you sir for the comment. I did not notice that one. It at least works now however it is not inserting the values from the userform, instead it inserts numbers like -1. I am more confused now

Comment: write a 
`Debug.print insert_str `
after your insert_str line  and look at it in the immediate window (STRG + G). 
This should be anyway a new question I think

Comment: in the immediate window it shows: update Classdate set attendanceStatus = 'Present' and Excuse = '' where classDate = '17/11/2022' and courseCode = 'ITWA' and studentID = 'IT01'. Does that mean that the insert_str has no error?

Comment: @RedHare I have posted a new question regarding this. Thank you for your assistance on this post!